# Android OnCompletionListener works on 3.0 but not 2.2?

Tags: java, android

My code get different behavior when the application runs on Android 2.2 and Android 3.0, code built for android 2.2 and provides no build errors in Eclipse. The Android 2.2 does not seem OnCompletionListener work as expected. Am I doing something wrong or is there any difference between Android 2.2 and 3.0 regarding OnCompletionListener.

My sample code is from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MediaPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "MediaPlayer";

    private SurfaceView m_preview;
        private SurfaceHolder m_holder;
        private Bundle m_extras;
        private String m_path;
        private MediaPlayer m_mediaPlayer;
        private int m_videoWidht;
        private int m_videoHeight;
        private boolean m_isVideoReadyToPlay;
        private boolean m_isVideoSizeKnown;
        private static final int LOCAL_VIDEO = 1;
        private static final int STREAM_VIDEO = 2;
        private static final String MEDIA = "media";

        private static final String FILE = "/mnt/sdcard/file1.avi";

        private WakeLock m_keepscreen;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::onCreate");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        m_keepscreen = pm.newWakeLock( PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,"MediaPlayerActivity");
        m_preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        m_holder = m_preview.getHolder();
        m_holder.addCallback(this);
        m_holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        m_extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        m_keepscreen.acquire();
    }

    private void playVideo(Integer media){
        doCleanUp();
        try{
                switch (media){
                case LOCAL_VIDEO :
                        m_path = FILE;
                        Log.i(TAG, "File: "+FILE);
                        if(m_path == ""){
                                //
                        }
                        break;
                case STREAM_VIDEO:
                        Log.i(TAG, "PlayVideo, cant stream video yet");
                        break;
                }

                m_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                m_mediaPlayer.setDataSource(m_path);
                m_mediaPlayer.setDisplay(m_holder);
                m_mediaPlayer.prepare();
                m_mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                m_mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                m_mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                /*
                m_mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::onCompletion");
                                startVideoPlayback();
                            }
                    });
                    */

                m_mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
                m_mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }catch (Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, "Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

        private void doCleanUp() {
                m_videoWidht = 0;
                m_videoHeight = 0;
                m_isVideoReadyToPlay = false;
                m_isVideoSizeKnown = false;

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                        int height) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::surfaceChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::surfaceCreated");
                playVideo(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::surfaceDestroyed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::videoSizeChanged");
                if( width == 0 || height == 0 ){
                        Log.i(TAG, "invalid video with("+width+")or height ("+height+")");
                }
                m_isVideoSizeKnown = true;
                m_videoWidht = width;
                m_videoHeight = height;
                if(m_isVideoReadyToPlay && m_isVideoSizeKnown){
                        startVideoPlayback();
                }
        }

        private void startVideoPlayback() {
                Log.i(TAG, "StartVideoPlayback");
                m_holder.setFixedSize(m_videoWidht, m_videoHeight);
                m_mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::onPrepared");
                m_isVideoReadyToPlay = true;
                if(m_isVideoReadyToPlay && m_isVideoSizeKnown){
                        startVideoPlayback();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //android 2.2 never get here
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::onCompletion");
                startVideoPlayback();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlayer::onBufferingUpdate: "+percent+" %");
        }

        @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

        @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

        private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (m_mediaPlayer != null) {
            m_mediaPlayer.release();
            m_mediaPlayer = null;
            m_keepscreen.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What **does** happen? What are you **expecting** to happen?

Comment: The function onCompletion is never called in android 2.2 but it is in 3.0.